# How do I insert multiple records into a mysql database, using a combination of checkboxes and html select

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

Suppose someone selects 2 students along with 1 teacher
How do I send/create 2 different records in MYSQL database, 
- one NEW Record for each student/teacher combo

## HTML:

1.) Here I can Select as many as "FOUR" students:

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="ALM[]" value="Bob" >Bob<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="ALM[]" value="Stacy" >Stacy<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="ALM[]" value="John" >John<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="ALM[]" value="Liam" >Liam<br />
```

2.) Here below I am Selecting "ONE" Teacher:

```
    <select name="TCH">
    <option value="Dan">Dan</option>
    <option vaule="Rick">Rick</option>
```

If I select Bob and Stacy (students) and Rick (teacher) I need. 
2 records 1.) Bob | Rick. 2.) Stacy | Rick.

## PHP:

This is my PHP where I Separate the incoming Checkbox Data and try to send to Database

```
$ALM = implode(',',$_POST['ALM']);
$TCH = $_POST['TCH']; 

$query = "INSERT INTO cl_st_tch (students_id,teachers_id) 
VALUES"; for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($ALM); $i++)
   $query .= "('" . $ALM[$i] . "','$TCH'),";
   $query = rtrim($query,',');
   mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error() );
```

What am I missing? Any Help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid multiple SQL queries a single query can be built.

```
    <?php
    $ALM = $_POST['ALM']; //implode(',',$_POST['ALM']);
    $TCH = $_POST['TCH'];
    $arr = array();
    $query = 'INSERT INTO cl_st_tch (students_id,teachers_id) VALUES ';
    foreach($ALM as $student){
            $arr[] = '('.$student.','.$TCH.')';
    }
    if(!empty($arr)) {
            $query .= implode(', ', $arr);
            mysql_query($query);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: And you just lost your database to bobby table.

Comment: @MTilsted please explain?

Comment: Your sql query contains unescaped user input, so if that input contains a special crafted content with sql, the users sql will be executed. But you should newer use mysql_query or other methods starting with mysql_ - Even the php documentation state this. Use Pdo instead.

Comment: this ans. is correct it, it will work for what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Since your ratio is 1:n (1 teacher to many students),

Iterate through each of the students and add a teacher to each one.

```
<?php

   $ALM = $_POST['ALM']; //implode(',',$_POST['ALM']);
   $TCH = $_POST['TCH']; 

   foreach($ALM as $student){
      $query = "INSERT INTO cl_st_tch (students_id,teachers_id) VALUES($student, $TCH)";
      mysql_query($query);
   }
?>
```

Comment: Worked...I think, when I check my database it shows only 0's (zeros) as the entry

Comment: Try to `print_r()` `$_POST['ALM']` to view the post contents.

Comment: It was missing (single quotes) '$students' around the Values